# copy an outlook appointment and send it to an other mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, rules, email-filter

Problem is, I don't have a work phone. But I would like to know when and where my appointments are on my private phone.
I need a rule that does the following:
- find all Outlook appointments
- copy the subject and the location to a new appointment
- send this appointment to a mail address

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Before implementing anything like this, you should talk to your Legal Department. Many regulatory and compliance requirements forbid the storage of company information on non-company devices.

Comment: This should be possible with Outlook VBA. Please do your research and attempt a solution before asking for help. Come back when you get stuck. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Option A** - Set up a forwarding rule.

The details might vary a bit by Outlook version, but here is how to do it in Outlook 2013.

- File menu --> Manage Rules & Alerts.
- E-mail Rules tab --> New Rule...
- Start from a blank rule, Apply rule on messages I receive.
- Next
- Find and check "which is a meeting invitation or update".
- Accept the warning about incompatibility with previous versions.
- Find and check "forward it to people or public group".
- Click on the "people or public group" link and select or create your external e-mail address as the recipient.
- OK
- Next
- Select any exceptions.
- Next
- Give the new rule a name and select whether to run it on existing messages.
- Finish!

**Caution:** Before implementing anything like this, you should talk to your Legal Department. Many regulatory and compliance requirements forbid the storage of company information on non-company devices and/or the forwarding of company e-mail to personal e-mail accounts.

**Option B** - Talk to your IT Department about the supported way to use your personal phone to check your business e-mail and calendar. They might have already implemented one or more solutions like Outlook Web Access, ActiveSync, Blackberry's Good for Enterprise, or Citrix's (XenApp) Secure Mail.